# Show time in format yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSS

Tags: java, datetime, formatting

My requirement is to convert a time (long) to a String with this date format:

> yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSS

For instance: `2017-03-07T03:52:31.298`

My implementation:

```
private final static String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss.SSS";

private final static DateFormat DF =
        new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH);

public static String formatTime(long time) {
    return DF.format(time).replace('_', 'T');
}
```

The underscore trick is to avoid  the `Illegal pattern character T` error I was getting if I had a `T` character in `DATE_FORMAT`. I am sure there is a better way to do this?
Also, I am sure more explicit names can be found for `DATE_FORMAT`/`DF`?

Comment: for others: the format is the iso8601 one, that is HIGHLY recommended to use everywhere. Actually, it just lacks the timezone part. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 .  Java now includes good-efficiency builtins for that one.

Comment: Please tell me you're not doing this for use in building SQL. Because that would be bad. Really bad. "I just found out my app was hacked six months ago" bad.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Not SQL. I develop a web service that returns timestamped audit records.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, this is [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME).

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.format(Instant.ofEpochMilli(time).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC))
// "2017-03-07T12:09:04.374"
```

Comment: the added bonus, iirc, is that "ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME" is quite more efficient than using a custom one. You may want to use instead ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME  to also have the offset included !

Comment: In that case you're probably best off with `Instant.ofEpochMilli(time).toString()`.

Comment: Somehow I get `Cannot be resolved` if I don't write `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` on that line.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul well it depends on your imports

Answer (score 17):

You can single-quote the 'T' to have it accepted as a String literal

```
private final static String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS";
```

Comment: Wonderful! As for the variable names, any advice maybe?

Answer (score 11):

#### Possible bug

The formatter is using an incorrect identifier for the hours. `hh` means " Hour in am/pm (1-12)", so it works with 12h format and a AM/PM marker. Since the formatter does not print the AM/PM marker, this is most likely a bug as it will not differentiate morning from afternoon, and return the same formatted `String` for two different dates.

You either want to use `HH` instead, which is "Hour in day (0-23)", or print the AM/PM marker with `a`.

#### Thread safety

> ```
> private final static DateFormat DF =
>          new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH);
> ```

This is a source of problems, because [`SimpleDateFormat` is not a thread-safe class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#synchronization):

> It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

With using a `SimpleDateFormat` as a constant, the same instance will be shared. If you happen to call the method `formatTime` from multiple threads at the same time, anything could happen; from an exception thrown, a wrong result, to, even worse, a right result sometimes. This code looks like it lives in a utility class, so all the more reasons it could be used concurrently.

The simple solution here is to let the method `formatTime` create the instance of `SimpleDateFormat` when it is called, with

```
public static String formatTime(long time) {
    return new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH).format(time);
}
```

If creating an instance of `SimpleDateFormat` each time the method is called turns out to be slow for your purposes, you could use a [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html), [like shown on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589986/date-conversion-with-threadlocal).

A better solution if you're under Java 8 is to use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), which is a thread-safe class.

```
private final static DateTimeFormatter DF =
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH);

public static String formatTime(long time) {
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(time);
    return DF.format(LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault()));
}
```